# Fetching MATIC / Polygon asset metadata from Opensea API / Polygonscan API

Tags: metadata, polygon, opensea, matic

I'm using the Opensea API to retrieve collectable asset metadata, all results from the call return as expected for assets tokenized on ethereum mainnet, however, any assets tokenized on the polygon network are not returned.

**What is the current correct way to retrieve assets' metadata ( image:, animation_url:, ...etc ) owned by a wallet address, listed on Opensea, tokenized on the polygon network?**

The Polygonscan API seems to have no documentation on retrieving assets for a particular wallet address, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Polygon is not supported by the api yet but planned in their V2

https://docs.opensea.io/reference/api-overview

> Looking for Polygon APIs? Our V2 API is not quite ready yet, but stay tuned for more updates soon!

Comment: When soon? been more than a year now :)